# Get object from collection without iterating over it

Tags: java, android, ibeacon

I'm trying to get the object from the collection beacons without having to iterate over that collection because that causes all get.rssi() values from the allBeacons list to get overwritten whilst only the values from the allBeacons list that are in the collection beacons have to be overwritten with their respective collection rssi value

how can I do this?

any help is greatly appreciated, this is my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
    @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(final Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                    new java.util.TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    for (final Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                                        {
                                            if (!allBeacons.contains(beacon)) {
                                                allBeacons.add(beacon);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    for (final Beacon allbeacons2 : allBeacons) {
                                        allbeacons2.setRssi(0);
                                    }

                                    for (final Beacon allbeacons3 : allBeacons) {
                                        if (beacons.contains(allbeacons3)) {
         //here the beacon of the allbeacons list should get the rssivalue of that beacon in the collection beacons 
                               allbeacons3.setRssi(?.getRssi());
                                        }
                                    }
                                    arrayL.clear();
                                    arrayL.addAll(allBeacons);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }
                    , 5000);

            //  }

        }

    });
```

Comment: can you be a bit more clear?

Comment: Fix indentations so we can read your code. I, for one, won't even try when it looks like that.

Comment: I've edited the code and changed them. sorry for that.

Comment: There is no way to get values from an arbitrary Collection other than from its iterator or by calling toArray.